# Redirect loop issue with Wordpress, URL is not changing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

If I go to `www.domain.com` it works fine. If I go to `http://domain.com` it gives me a redirect loop. I commented the .htaccess and it worked, but then I realised the redirects were caused by the WP application itself (if I `exit()` in the first line of the index.php both URLs work).

After many days trying to solve this problem, I started debugging the WordPress code and found the function `wp_redirect` on pluggable.php. It was just checking if it was porta8080.com.br, and redirecting to www.porta8080.com.br.

the point is that, the redirection wasn't changing the URL. so it was being redirect everytime the page was loaded. I tried to do this verification in my own way in the very first line of index.php, but I got the same error.

I made it work with `header('refresh:0,url=www.domain.com')` in the first line of index.php, but it gets cached (probably) and stops working after a few hours.

why isn't the URL changing? or how can I stop this cache with the second method?

any ideas?! it's getting me crazy for over a week now!

Comment: remove the `wp_redirect` call?

Comment: are you suggesting to remove it? but where is it being called? I just intercepted the execution of wp_redirect inside that function, not at the calling moment